# History of 7 Teveis

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

****Looking for answers as to what happened in Jewish history on this date. It can include both positive and negative occurrences. It can also include birthdays or Yarzheits of well known personalities that happened on this date.**

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

**All interesting answers will be up voted.**

***Best answer will be accepted.*****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liberties were granted to Russian Jews by the Czar Alexander I in 1804, which actually spelled economic ruin for much of the Jewish community